# kerberos Authentication on my Local VM with Forgerock AM deployed locally on my tomcat

Tags: windows, authentication, tomcat, kerberos, forgerock

I have filled in the required infomation in the kerberos node (eg. SPN, Keytab file path and then trusted realms as well )

I am not getting any prompt to enter the user details. also
In AM log file I see "HTTP-Auth-failed" !!
[AM WARNING LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFJyo.png)
[NODE SPECIFICATIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0AsY.png)

NOTE: My domain controller and my AM is on the same VM. I am using a different user (demo1) in my AD while testing the flow for the kerberos with other service account (serviceuser1)

what might be the issue in this case ?

I tried replacing keytab file path in different location where the AM can read it.

I even tried to change the browser from firefox to edge .